# Possible discrepancies in pom.xml preventing Spring mappings while launching war on Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I've been working at this problem for quite some time, and am at a loss.
What baffles me beyond belief is that I once had this configuration working with the pom unaltered which makes me think the issue involves configuration within IntelliJ. I thought that may have been due to using an older version of Tomcat 7, but when I went back to try that version (7.0.92), I had the same result. Currently I am on version 7.0.99.

The issue involves no errors, for some reason the Spring mappings aren't being hit, which were previously all logged within the output in the server log. I've tried many tweaks to the pom to no avail.
Currently the Application class has the @SpringBootApplication annotation.
The pom was written previously (so apologies if a bit unweildy); I'm just working to refactor bits at this point to attempt to get it working.
Any help is greatly appreciated, I've scoured the internet quite thoroughly and have been banging my head against the wall for some time now...

Here is the pom for reference:
**

EDITED

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>Mobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>MAMA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>MAMA</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ckeditor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ckeditor-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ua-parser</groupId>
            <artifactId>uap-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.kcthota</groupId>
            <artifactId>emoji4j</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <!-- makesure correct version here -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.supercsv/super-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.supercsv/super-csv-dozer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv-dozer</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgres -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/ckeditor -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>ckeditor</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <delimiters>
                        <delimiter>@</delimiter>
                    </delimiters>
                    <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8045</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <!-- Useful to run application locally -->
        <profile>
            <id>dev8</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/config/dev</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>application.properties</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.sortpom</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-sortpom-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sort</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <sortProperties>true</sortProperties>
                            <nrOfIndentSpace>4</nrOfIndentSpace>
                            <sortDependencies>groupId,artifactId</sortDependencies>
                            <sortPlugins>groupId,artifactId</sortPlugins>
                            <keepBlankLines>true</keepBlankLines>
                            <expandEmptyElements>false</expandEmptyElements>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.8</source>
                            <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <requireMavenVersion>
                                    <message>You are running an older version of Maven. requires at least Maven 3.1</message>
                                    <version>[3.1.0,)</version>
                                </requireMavenVersion>
                                <requireJavaVersion>
                                    <message>You are running an older version of Java. requires at least JDK ${java.version}</message>
                                    <version>[${java.version}.0,)</version>
                                </requireJavaVersion>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: To exclude IntelliJ IDEA configuration problem you can try to build it using the command line Maven and deploy the war manually. Does the issue persist or does it occur only when you run from IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: You are mixing jars from different Spring versions. Sprnig Boot 1.4 uses Spring 4.2, youa re including a Spring 5.2 dependency. You also have a conflicting Servlet API dependency (2.5 and 3.1) in your dependencies. Remove the `org.springframework` dependencies (and dependency management) and remove the `spring-data-releasetrain` as well. All of those are managed by Spring Boot. All in all your dependencies are quite a mess.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - it persists when starting tomcat server from command line as well..

Comment: @M.Deinum - I updated the pom with some changes, it's still not working. I had to add a few back in, like spring-beans, spring-orm, and spring-context...still no luck. If you have any more insight, it's greatly appreciated. I feel like I've really exhausted my options.

Comment: Don't add those spring dependencies back. Those are included in the different starters you already have. Also instead of ORM you should include the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and remove the hibernate dependencies as well. For the Hibernate Validator one use `spring-boot-starter-validation` instead. Also apparently you are using Spring Boot but aren't using the proper plugin to create the deployable. You should use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and not the jar or war plugin.

Comment: @M.Dinum - thank you, your advice has helped me progress considerably...your time is greatly appreciated!!